# Netty convert HTTP/1.1 pipeline to dual HTTP/2 HTTP/1.1

Tags: java, kotlin, netty

I built a simple pipeline for serving HTTP/1.1 content with Netty, and I'm looking to see how I can convert it to HTTP/2. I see various classes for converting between frames and negotiating, but I can't figure out how to assemble them into a pipeline. The following code is in Kotlin. The main issue I have is with ALPN negotiation, and also converting the frames right in both directions.

```
val bootstrap = ServerBootstrap()
bootstrap.group(transport.bossGroup, transport.workerGroup)
    .channelFactory(transport.factory)
    .childHandler(object : ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        public override fun initChannel(ch: SocketChannel) {
            ch.pipeline().addLast("ssl", sslContext.newHandler(ch.alloc()))

            ch.pipeline().addLast("codec", HttpServerCodec())
            ch.pipeline().addLast("keepAlive", HttpServerKeepAliveHandler())
            ch.pipeline().addLast("aggregator", HttpObjectAggregator(65536))

            ch.pipeline().addLast("burstLimiter", burstLimiter)

            ch.pipeline().addLast(
                "readTimeoutHandler",
                ReadTimeoutHandler(60)
            )
            ch.pipeline().addLast(
                "writeTimeoutHandler",
                WriteTimeoutHandler(60)
            )

            ch.pipeline().addLast("streamer", ChunkedWriteHandler())
            ch.pipeline().addLast("handler", CustomHandler(httpHandler))
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to make use of the `Http2MultiplexHandler` together with the `Http2StreamFrameToHttpObjectCodec`. This will allow you to speak HTTP2 while still provide you with the same "objects" in your handler as with HTTP1.

So it would be something like:

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(Http2FrameCodecBuilder.forServer().build());
ch.pipeline().addLast(new Http2MultiplexHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) {
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new Http2StreamFrameToHttpObjectCodec(true));
        // Add all your other handlers that act on HTTP1 objects
    }
});
```

If you also need to add handlers for SSL etc depends a bit on your use case.

For a more detailed example you can also consult the http2 multiplex examples that are part of netty itself. These handle H1/H2 at the same time depending on what the client asks for.

Answer (score 0):

What about a non-code solution - e.g. front-end netty with Apache - let Apache do the HTTP/2 for you? And then just pass on the trafic to your pipeline [see the Apache HTTP2 How To](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html)